# Take a variable from a data frame row based on index found on a column

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to add a new column in a data frame showing the variable based on the index shown in the last column of the data frame.

My data frame is something like this:

```
 v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
1  A  K  F  W  2
2  B  O  J  Q  4
3  C  M  T  A  3
4  D  Z  R  B  2
```

so want to get this

```
  v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6
1  A  K  F  W  2  K
2  B  O  J  Q  4  Q
3  C  M  T  A  3  T
4  D  Z  R  B  2  Z
```

at the end.

Has anyone any ideas on how to do this??

Comment: please consider to add "ready to use data" in your next question. For e.g. `dput(yourData)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use row/column indexing by `cbind`ing the 'v5' i.e. column index with row index (`1:nrow(df1)` or `seq_len(nrow(df1))`) to extract the elements corresponding to the first 4 columns of dataset and assign it to 'v6'

```
df1$v6 <- df1[-5][cbind(1:nrow(df1), df1$v5)]
df1
#  v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6
#1  A  K  F  W  2  K
#2  B  O  J  Q  4  Q
#3  C  M  T  A  3  T
#4  D  Z  R  B  2  Z
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option in base R. We can use `sapply` to loop through every rows in the data frame to get the string based on the index in the 5th column.

```
dat$V6 <- sapply(1:nrow(dat), function(x) dat[-5][x, dat[[5]][x]])
dat
#   v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 V6
# 1  A  K  F  W  2  K
# 2  B  O  J  Q  4  Q
# 3  C  M  T  A  3  T
# 4  D  Z  R  B  2  Z
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = " v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
1  A  K  F  W  2
                  2  B  O  J  Q  4
                  3  C  M  T  A  3
                  4  D  Z  R  B  2",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

tried the following with dplyr, added a group variable to identify the row. the mutate isn't perfect as I am reffering df again in it - if anyone can correct it pls share :). the grp var is requried for the row index.

```
dfNew = df %>% mutate(grp = seq(1:nrow(df))) %>% group_by(grp) %>% mutate(v6 = df[grp,v5]) %>% ungroup() %>% select(-grp)
```

Got the result but with a few warnings too (think they were because of the char encoding). Agree to the comment above please add a line of code for the data creation

```
dfNew
# A tibble: 4 x 6
      v1     v2     v3     v4    v5    v6
    <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <dbl> <chr>
1      a      k      f      w     2     k
2      b      o      j      q     4     q
3      c      m      t      a     3     t
4      d      z      r      b     2     z
```